# Run Access Report Silently?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to run an Access Report (to file and to printer) 'silently' (i.e., without popping up Access) because it is running from a service-application and even using Interact with Desktop and as well as running the "Interactive Services Detection" service doesn't seem to help. (FYI:  All of this code works fine with the calling application NOT running as a service)

My Access report has a couple of datatables (that I am inserting into for the report - no problems there) and the following code:

```
Function RunTurnReport()
   ReportPrint "Turn Report"
   Application.Quit
End Function

Public Sub ReportPrint(rpt as string)
   dim outfile as string
   outfile = "C:\reports\" & rpt & ".rtf"
   Application.DoCmd.OpenReport rpt, acViewNormal,,,acWindowNormal
   Application.DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, rpt, acFormatRTF, outfile
End Sub
```

That is from the Access perspective.  The report itself just gets its data from a simple query of the table mentioned above.

Inside my 'calling application', it uses embedded VBA.  I have tried 2 methods to do this:

Method 1:  Shell to run macro that runs the RunTurnReport function

```
Const ReportLocation = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE"" ""C:\Reports\Reporting.mdb"" /X macroRunTurnReport"

Private Sub RunTurnupReport_OnTrue()
   Dim id As Variant
   id = Shell(ReportLocation, vbMinimizedNoFocus)
End Sub
```

Method 2:  Access Automation

```
Dim MSA As New Access.Application

Private Sub RunTurnupReport_OnTrue()
   MSA.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Reports\Reporting.mdb"
   MSA.Run "RunTurnReport"
  
   set MSA=nothing
End Sub
```

Both methods seem to have an issue when the VBA embedded application is running as a service due to Access popping up messages and then seeing "A program running on this computer is trying to display a message"

I just can't figure out how to run these reports (with calling application as a service) without having this issue :(

Comment: Office applications, including Access, were/are not intended to be run unattended. They are designed to be run by humans and there is no telling when a message/dialog might pop up. I would find a different reporting tool to generate reports.

Comment: Are you aware that you are printing the report with `DoCmd.OpenReport`?

Comment: Is there another way to print it?